# How do I calculate the complex integral $\int_c\frac{1}{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

How do I calculate the complex integral $\displaystyle\int_c\frac{1}{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z$, where $c$ is a direct line from $z=0$ to $z=1+2i$?

Is it possible solving such the integral? I mean $\frac{1}{z^2}$ does not exist in $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

One can parametrize the path $c$ by $z(t)=(1+2i)t$ for $0\leqslant t\leqslant1$, then the integral becomes $\int\limits_0^1\frac1{(1+2i)^2t^2}(1+2i)\mathrm dt=\frac1{1+2i}\int\limits_0^1\frac1{t^2}\mathrm dt$. What do you think of this last integral?

Comment: thank you. I only know last integral is a improper integral but i don't know how to calculate that. Does it have real value?

Comment: The last integral is a Riemann integral, and you should really know that it diverges at $0$.

Comment: thanks so the problem has no solution right?